# How to make multiple endpoint from the source connection in jsplumb

Tags: jsplumb

I'm using jsPlumb to connect divs with multiple endpoints. I'm trying to prevent multiple connectors between the same two divs. So for example, if I have divs A, B, C, I would like to have different end points so I can connect A to B and A to C from different end points, There is nothing given about this in the documentation

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Un grouping the drop point and the actual link creation point and defining Multiple Anchors resolved the issue

```
if (sd && td) {
              var width = 1 / parentCount;
              var left = width * idx;
              var anchors = parentCount > 1 ? ["BottomCenter",        [left,0,0,0]] : ["BottomCenter", "TopCenter" ],
connection = window.jsPlumb.connect({
             source: s, target: t, newConnection:true, anchors: anchors
            , deleteEndpointsOnDetach: true
                                         });
```